# Add a second element to div with :after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Hi I've got follow div:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I would like to add a second div to the `.box` with pseudo class `after`. I thought it would work like this, but nothing happens. It should look like this:

[image]

How to do this with `after`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  display:block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're code is right, the only thing missing is the property display to that element. Just add a `display: block` on the `:after` element. To easily manipulate the pseudo-element, make the main element `position: relative`, then the `:after` as `position: absolute` and place it based on the `.box` `div`, something like this :

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative; /* Made it relative */
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: -1px; /* To compensate the border on the main element */
  background-color: blue;
  left: 100%; /* To place it after the main element */
}
```

If you truly need another div, try adding some javascript, like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').append('<div class="another-box"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Hi, yes I wrote it wrong, edited the title. :) I will try it thanks.

Comment: No worries, I also edited my answer to do the render as you asked

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -21px;
  top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```